# Need to differentiate bootbox.alert() and bootbox.confirm() ,both styles of modal in same page

Tags: css, bootbox

I have multiple bootbox.alert() and bootbox.confirm() modals in same page need to clearly add different styles but no luck so far, how can I define my own style classes for these modals.

```
var alertModal = bootbox.alert(
                {
                    title: "<i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' style='font-size: 20px; color: white'></i> Alert",
                    message: "Please select Patient from Queue",
                })
            alertModal.find('.modal-header')
                .css(
                {
                    'background-color': 'red',
                    'color': 'white'
                }
                );
            alertModal.find('.modal-footer')
                .css({
                    'background-color': 'green',
                    'color': 'white'
                }
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation link [Dialog Options](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#dialog-options), you can see that, an option for optional className is given.

```
var alertModal = bootbox.alert(
{
    title: "<i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' style='font-size: 20px; color: white'></i> Alert",
    message: "Please select Patient from Queue",
    className:"your custom class name here"
})
```

You can create separate classes for alert and confirm and pass it in the options

Comment: That is very easy configuration by bootbox. Thank you very much Gautam Naik.